# find what compilers are installed using python

Tags: python, windows, file, path-variables

I know this qustion may seem astract, but I will try my best to be specific.

I wait to gain a [file refrence](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/file.html) to the exectuble of compilers from all types installed in an Windows 10 operting system. Is there is any way to get that list of compiler refrences? (Maybe using the file paths?) and if not, How can I get referance and check weather a spesific compiler installed, who's path is unknown? (more specificly, [Microsoft's C++ compiler](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/features/cplusplus/))

Comment: Have you tried anything, done any research?

Comment: The OS doesn't know what a compiler is. As such it cannot provide any means to determine the set of installed compilers. You're going to have to search all locations where compilers may wind up getting installed. There are lots of locations you'll need to search even if you limit yourself to a single compiler. I recall that Microsoft have recently started deploying a COM object that allows you to enumerate installed Visual Studio instances, but cannot find reference documentation now. I believe this was limited to VS 2019 and later, too, so it may not be helpful to you.

Comment: @AMC well, I tried googleing it, was not so succsesfull. Also tried to find out where compilers are usully installed, and it seem thereis no definite location